# IIS 7 and windows authentication from outside the web server's domain

Tags: windows, iis, authentication, dns

I've deployed my site in IIS 7, and can browse to it fine on the web server.
I've set it to windows authentication (only), and when browsing from outside the domain, I want to be challenged for credentials, and gain access when entering a domain\username & password combination that exists in the AD.

401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. My iis logs

I put a dummy site in IIS and set it to anonymous, I can browse to this no problem also.

I checked that windows auth was installed/set up on the web server, and it is.

What set of config parameters do I need to get this working?

*yes, I know I should use some sort of custom authentication provider with accounts stored in a database, but I don't want to go through that yet.

Thanks for any advice, words of wisdom.

Comment: You are getting this error because your trying to access a website that is using a windows authentication, and your website is unable to determine, which user your trying to use.  In other words its not designed to be used outside of the domain.

Comment: thank you for your input.  yes, this is what i imagined... the question is then, how do i make my website prompt for a password and accept the domain\username &password combo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your only option is to enable basic authentication. The user should then enter the full domain\username with the password. Beware though that basic authentication uses just base64 which can be very easily decoded. So if you enable basic authentication you have to use SSL/TLS as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer, you can get it to prompt you by: Internet Options > Security > Custom level > User authentication > Logon > Prompt for username and password.